# Traffic Meter Cisco ASA / Internet Bandwitdh Meter

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Traffic Meter graph(on Welcome screeen) on Cisco ASA 6.1 counts the bandwitdch for 5 minutes. Can i get a outside usage report/graph for 2 weeks?

If it is not possible, do you know any application for testing internet bandwidth usage for whole company?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask your ISP if they have a monitoring portal that you can use. If not, set up your own solution, as the ASA (and pretty much every network device out there) supports SNMP. Popular choices for bandwidth monitoring are MRTG and Cacti, plus a plethora of buyware.

Comment: Tnx Pauska. I have installed PRTG Network Monitor and i will give that a try.

Comment: Yep SNMP is how pretty much everyone does this dude, +1 for pauska